# Unknown Interpretation for "_/_" despite importing Arith

Tags: coq

I was trying to write a function to converts a `nat` to a `string` in `coq`. Here is my attempt.

```
Require Import Arith String.

(*
  append is part of the string library. Its signature is
                 (s1 : string) : string -> string
*)

Fixpoint convert_nat_to_string (n : nat) : string :=
match n with
  | 0 => String "0" EmptyString 
  | 1 => String "1" EmptyString
  | 2 => String "2" EmptyString
  | 3 => String "3" EmptyString
  | 4 => String "4" EmptyString
  | 5 => String "5" EmptyString
  | 6 => String "6" EmptyString
  | 7 => String "7" EmptyString
  | 8 => String "8" EmptyString
  | 9 => String "9" EmptyString
  | _ => (append (convert_nat_to_string (n/10))) (convert_nat_to_string (n mod 10))
end.
```

However, on the last branch, `coqide` gives me an error

> Error: Unknown interpretation for notation "_ / _".

even though I have imported the `Arith` library. Does anyone know why I am  getting this error message?

---

Proof that `/` is part of `Arith`:

```
Coq < Require Import Arith.
[Loading ML file z_syntax_plugin.cmxs ... done]
[Loading ML file quote_plugin.cmxs ... done]
[Loading ML file newring_plugin.cmxs ... done]
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked

Coq < Check 5/10.
5 / 10
     : nat
```

Comment: I'm using Coq 8.6. I tried your code as is and I can't reproduce the error you see. You'll see another error having to do with totality. You can deal with it using `Program Fixpoint` or following the approach proposed [here](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/draft/qc-current/Typeclasses.html) (look for `string_of_nat`).

Comment: @AntonTrunov cheers for that. I tried running the code directly from the command line and got the same error as you mentioned. However, while running it from the IDE gives me the error that I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, because I'm not a CoqIDE user. You might want to give ProofGeneral + company-coq (optional) a shot :) I see a lot of questions involving CoqIDE. I admit though, that configuring Emacs might not be among your priorities here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Coq 8.6, this function is available in `Coq.Arith.PeanoNat`.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.

Check 10 / 5. (* --> 10 / 5 : nat *)
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur. Do you know if there is any way to check the version of `coq` used by `coqide` so I can confirm that this indeed is the issue?

Comment: Because when I run `coqtop -v` in the command line, I get the version as `8.5pl13`.

Comment: @iamwhoiam My version of coqide displays the Coq version it is using when it starts, on the bottom-right corner. If that doesn't exist on yours, you can maybe try the "about" menu on the toolbar. What OS are you using?

Comment: I figured it out. It's `8.4pl5`. So I believe the error is due to the different versions.Though, I can't really confirm this by downloading another version as the official site seems to be down right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes it's down and it's likely to stay down until tomorrow. You can try installing Coq from OPAM or from Nix (or from sources https://github.com/coq/coq). If you're on Windows though I have no solution for you (compiling from sources on Windows would be possible, but complicated).

Comment: @Zimmi48 these days compiling on Windows using OPAM is not a lot more complicated than compiling on OSX. Basically: install "OPAM for Windows" [they do a have a click installer]m,tweak some repositories; install dependencies, compile!